# Почему не уходит Post запрос

Tags: javascript

Почему не уходит Post запрос?
Что не так в этом коде?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Страница отправки запросов</title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>

  <h1>Заполните форму для отправки запроса</h1>
  <form id="myForm" name="message">
    <label for="age">ip адрес:</label><br>
    <input id="age" name="age" value="25">
    <br>

    <label for="name">имя:</label><br>
    <input id="name" name="name" value="dima">

    <br>  
    <button name="send">Отправить</button>
  </form>
  
  <script>
    function sendForm(e){
      console.log('sendForm -> start');
      var formData = new FormData(document.forms.message);
      const messageData = JSON.stringify(formData);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
      xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:9003/gw/api/send");
      xhr.send(messageData);
    }

    var sendButton = document.message.send;
    sendButton.addEventListener("click", sendForm);

 </script>

 </body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что запрос не уходит?

Comment: на этом порту запущен сервер и он ни чего не принимает. Возможно что-то не так с Json объектом. Почему он передается с строке запроса. Это так и должно быть?

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае надо писать так:

```
function sendForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Так как в ином случае происходит сабмит формы с перезагрузкой страницы (так как `button` по умолчанию имеет тип `submit`). По-умолчанию, без указания метода отправки в форме - происходит GET запрос - отсюда и появление JSON в строке запроса.

---

Еще у кнопки можно поставить тип `button`, тогда `e.preventDefault();` уже не нужен будет